# Codeigniter pagination is not appeared

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, activerecord, pagination

i have view `vkategorimaterial` like this

```
<table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4">Tampilkan<?php 
                    echo form_open('c_kategorimaterial/cari');
                    echo nbs();$intext=array('name' => 'cari', 'class' => 'GUI');
                    echo form_input($intext);
                    echo nbs(); $inbutton=array('value' => 'Cari', 'class' => 'button');
                    echo form_submit($inbutton);
                    echo form_close();
                    ?></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4"><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/c_kategorimaterial/tambah"><img class ="create" src="<?php echo base_url();?>img/create.png"></a></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Nomor</td>
                    <td>Kode Kategori Material / Jasa</td>
                    <td>Nama Material / Jasa</td>
                    <td>Perintah</td>
                </tr>
                 <?php     if ( !empty($rows) ) 
                      {  
                            $no = 1;   
                            foreach ($rows as $row) { ?>  
                            <tr id="row">  
                             <td><?php echo $no;?></td>  
                             <td><?php echo $row->Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa;?></td>  
                             <td><?php echo $row->Nama_Material_Jasa;?></td>  
                             <td> <a href="<?php echo site_url('c_kategorimaterial/ubah/'.$row->Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa.'/'.$row->Nama_Material_Jasa);?>"><img class="perintah" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>img/update.png"></a><a href="<?php echo site_url('c_kategorimaterial/hapus/'.$row->Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa);?>" onclick="return confirm('akan dihapus, anda yakin ?');"><img class="perintah" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>img/delete.png"></a></td>                           

                            </tr>  
                            <?php  
                             $no++;  
                            }  
                     } 
                     else { ?>  
            <tr id="row">  
            <td colspan="6" align="center">Tabel Kosong</td>  
            </tr>

        <?php  
        }  
        ?>  
        </table>
       <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
```

then i made the controller named `c_kategorimaterial` here is the `index` part

```
function index()
{
    $query = $this->m_kategorimaterial->get();  
    $config['base_url'] =  base_url().'index.php/c_kategorimaterial/index/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $query->num_rows();
    $config['per_page'] = 5; 
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['rows'] = $query->result();
    $data['title'] = 'QB Kategori Material';
    $this->load->view('menu',$data);
    $this->load->view('v/vkategorimaterial');

}
```

i want to make a pagination that showing 5 rows per page. and here is the model of `m_kategorimaterial->get`

```
 $this->db->order_by('Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa','DESC');
    $query = $this->db->get('ms_kategori_material',5);
    return $query;
```

why does the pagination is not showing ? here is the result of `print_r($data['rows']);`

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa] => KKMJ006 [Nama_Material_Jasa] => Biji ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa] => KKMJ004 [Nama_Material_Jasa] => Teneh ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa] => KKMJ001 [Nama_Material_Jasa] => Air ) )
```

Comment: `$config['base_url'] =  base_url().'index.php/c_kategorimaterial/index/';`

Comment: @deepak oh thank you deepak, i have corrected the thread above and my code, and it still doesn't make my pagination showed. where did i go wrong ?

Comment: make sure records are more than  $config['per_page'] = 5;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this block

```
function index()
{
   $query = $this->m_kategorimaterial->get();  
   $config['base_url'] =  base_url().'index.php/c_kategorimaterial/index/';
   $config['total_rows'] = $query->num_rows();
   $config['per_page'] = 5;        
   $data['rows'] = $query->result();
   $this->pagination->initialize($config);
   $this->load->vars($data); // !!!
   $data['title'] = 'QB Kategori Material';
   $this->load->view('menu',$data);
   $this->load->view('v/vkategorimaterial');

}
```

And in your view try this,

```
echo $this->pagination->create_links();
```

Comment: i've tried your index, and adding `echo $this->pagination->create_links();` and the pagination still not showing

Comment: in that case your `$data['rows']` does not have any records. Try `print_r($data['rows'])` see if it prints anything

Comment: it shows blank white screen with `Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa] => KKMJ006 [Nama_Material_Jasa] => Biji ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa] => KKMJ004 [Nama_Material_Jasa] => Teneh ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa] => KKMJ001 [Nama_Material_Jasa] => Air ) ) `

Comment: what is `$query->num_rows()` this value ?

Comment: it shows `3` because there's only 3 records in my DB do i have to add more record to make it displayed ?

Comment: and is this your view path `v/vkategorimaterial` ?

Comment: try to make `$config['per_page'] = 5;` to `$config['per_page'] = 2;`

Comment: the pagination is displayed, but the grid still showing 3 records, any idea how to reduce the grid according to the `per page` config ?

Comment: i am using this syntax `$query = $this->db->get('ms_kategori_material',5);` and the pagination is showing. and when i change into `$query = $this->db->get('ms_kategori_material',2);` the pagination disappeared

Answer (score 0):

`echo $this->pagination->create_links();`

Comment: do i need to make more record like 10 record to make it appear ?

Comment: Your per page post is set to 5. So you need atleast 6 post to appear the links.

Comment: i change the config into `$config['per_page'] = 2; ` and the model into `$query = $this->db->get('ms_kategori_material',2);` and there's 3 record in the database. the pagination is not showing

Answer (score 0):

Include pagination library in controller

```
$this->load->library('pagination');

And alter a line in your controller to

$this->load->view('v/vkategorimaterial',$data);
```

Here is helpful link for you [Codeigniter Pagination](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html):